# how to decode uniswap universal router arguments?

Tags: uniswap

```
var error = new Error(message);
                ^
```

Error: invalid arrayify value (argument="value", value={"args":["0x0b00",["0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038d7ea4c68000","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"],{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x64e5b314"}],"functionFragment":{"type":"function","name":"execute","constant":false,"inputs":[{"name":"commands","type":"bytes","indexed":null,"components":null,"arrayLength":null,"arrayChildren":null,"baseType":"bytes","_isParamType":true},{"name":"inputs","type":"bytes[]","indexed":null,"components":null,"arrayLength":-1,"arrayChildren":{"name":null,"type":"bytes","indexed":null,"components":null,"arrayLength":null,"arrayChildren":null,"baseType":"bytes","_isParamType":true},"baseType":"array","_isParamType":true},{"name":"deadline","type":"uint256","indexed":null,"components":null,"arrayLength":null,"arrayChildren":null,"baseType":"uint256","_isParamType":true}],"outputs":[],"payable":true,"stateMutability":"payable","gas":null,"_isFragment":true},"name":"execute","signature":"execute(bytes,bytes[],uint256)","sighash":"0x3593564c","value":{"type":"BigNumber","hex":"0x038d7ea4c68000"}}, code=INVALID_ARGUMENT, version=bytes/5.7.0)
at Logger.makeError (R:\mev\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:238:21)
at Logger.throwError (R:\mev\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:247:20)
at Logger.throwArgumentError (R:\mev\node_modules@ethersproject\logger\lib\index.js:250:21)
at arrayify (R:\mev\node_modules@ethersproject\bytes\lib\index.js:94:19)
at AbiCoder.decode (R:\mev\node_modules@ethersproject\abi\lib\abi-coder.js:98:66)
at decodeUniversalRouterSwap (R:\mev\index.js:1325:38)
at initialChecks (R:\mev\index.js:1381:17)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
at async processTransaction (R:\mev\index.js:1397:24) {
reason: 'invalid arrayify value',
code: 'INVALID_ARGUMENT',
argument: 'value',
value: TransactionDescription {
args: [
'0x0b00',
[
'0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038d7ea4c68000',
'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'
],
BigNumber { _hex: '0x64e5b314', _isBigNumber: true },
commands: '0x0b00',
inputs: [
'0x000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000200000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000038d7ea4c68000',
'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'
],
deadline: BigNumber { _hex: '0x64e5b314', _isBigNumber: true }
],
functionFragment: {
type: 'function',
name: 'execute',
constant: false,
inputs: [
ParamType {
name: 'commands',
type: 'bytes',
indexed: null,
components: null,
arrayLength: null,
arrayChildren: null,
baseType: 'bytes',
_isParamType: true
},
ParamType {
name: 'inputs',
type: 'bytes[]',
indexed: null,
components: null,
arrayLength: -1,
arrayChildren: ParamType {
name: null,
type: 'bytes',
indexed: null,
components: null,
arrayLength: null,
arrayChildren: null,
baseType: 'bytes',
_isParamType: true
},
baseType: 'array',
_isParamType: true
},
ParamType {
name: 'deadline',
type: 'uint256',
indexed: null,
components: null,
arrayLength: null,
arrayChildren: null,
baseType: 'uint256',
_isParamType: true
}
],
outputs: [],
payable: true,
stateMutability: 'payable',
gas: null,
_isFragment: true,
constructor: [Function: FunctionFragment] {
from: [Function (anonymous)],
fromObject: [Function (anonymous)],
fromString: [Function (anonymous)],
isFunctionFragment: [Function (anonymous)]
},
format: [Function (anonymous)]
},
name: 'execute',
signature: 'execute(bytes,bytes[],uint256)',
sighash: '0x3593564c',
value: BigNumber { _hex: '0x038d7ea4c68000', _isBigNumber: true }
}
}

Im expecting to decode

Comment: Please add the code that is producing this error and consider only adding the relevant part of the error message.

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/Elnaril/uniswap-universal-router-decoder

```
from uniswap_universal_router_decoder import RouterCodec

trx_input = "0x3593564c000000000000000000 ... 90095b5c4e9f5845bba"  # the trx input to decode
codec = RouterCodec()
decoded_trx_input = codec.decode.function_input(trx_input)
```